# how to connect iis using quic protocol on Windows10

Tags: http, iis, quic, http3

The whole process was on
https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows10/4e2a1370-30ba-4bf4-a460-98664a0172ef

TLDR:
I configure an iis server and bind https with default config,but I can't connect to it using quic protocol.The code I use was the "sample" tool provided in https://github.com/microsoft/msquic,with its client feature,port 443.
But when I run the "sample" tool's server feature on the target machine,and connect to it using the client feature on another machine,it works.

Question:
Does iis server support quic protocol on 443 port by default,if not how can I connect to the iis server using quic?

Comment: Such support (HTTP/3, QUIC) can only come when the Windows TCP/IP stack upgrades. Not sure if Windows/IIS vNext will include any of this. As TLS 3 support takes a few years to finish, I don't think HTTP/3 will take shorter.

Comment: I see,thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these instructions [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/enabling-http-3-support-on-windows-server-2022/ba-p/2676880) and possibly also these trouble shooting instructions [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/troubleshooting-http-3-in-http-sys/ba-p/3273139).

Essentially, you will need to run:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters" /v EnableHttp3 /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters" /v EnableAltSvc /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```